# Golang unexpected EOF

Tags: go, eof, inflate

Here's my code, I'm new to Go.
I tried googling the issue, but I can't quite put my finger on it.
I think it has something to do with the `Read()` method.

```
package main

import (
    ...
)

type compressor struct {
    content []byte
}

func (r *compressor) compress() []byte {
    ...
}

func (r *compressor) decompress() []byte {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    dc := flate.NewReader(&buffer)
    _, err := dc.Read(r.content)
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    return buffer.Bytes()
}

func main() {
    fileName := os.Args[1]
    fmt.Println(os.Args)
    contents, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Print("Uncompressed data: ")
    fmt.Println(len(contents))

    comp := compressor{contents}
    buffer := comp.decompress()
    fmt.Print("Uncompressed data: ")
    fmt.Println(len(comp.decompress()))

    err = ioutil.WriteFile(fileName+".decjc", buffer, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Here's the output

> ```
> dylan@skynet:~/Documents/EXP/jc$ ./jc data.txt.jc 
> [./jc data.txt.jc]
> Uncompressed data: 2364480
> 2018/06/29 21:41:35 unexpected EOF
> ```

Comment: Where is the error being thrown? What line?

Comment: You're reading from an empty buffer, so there's nothing to decompress.

Comment: The buffer actually does contain content

Comment: Perhaps your first line in `decompress()` you meant `bytes.NewReader(r.content)`

Comment: @Dylan: no it does not. You're reading from `buffer` which is a `bytes.Buffer` which you never put any data into.

Comment: Have another look at [io.Reader.Read](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). It reads *into* its argument, not *from* it. Where it's reading from depends entirely on the implementation. flate's reader reads from the thing you pass to NewReader.

Comment: Please take a look at this Github issue comment: https://github.com/revel/revel/issues/566#issuecomment-42019967

Comment: @andy: Thanks! I ran into the same issue and the comment you linked is the true solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After doing a trace on the particular code in question I have come to the following answer.

[/src/bytes/reader.go 70](https://golang.org/src/bytes/reader.go)

```golang
func (r *Reader) ReadByte() (byte, error) {
    ...

    if r.i >= int64(len(r.s)) {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }

    ....
}
```

There are four functions in bytes/reader that can return `io.EOF`, and zero functions that can return `io.ErrUnexpectedEOF`. The four functions that can return `io.EOF` are:

```golang
Read(b []byte)
ReadAt(b []byte, off int64)
ReadByte()
ReadRune()
```

[/src/compress/flate/inflate.go 698](https://golang.org/src/compress/flate/inflate.go)

```golang
func (f *decompressor) moreBits() error {
    c, err := f.r.ReadByte()
    if err != nil {
        return noEOF(err)
    }

    ...
}
```

Of the four functions that can return `io.EOF`, only one function in flate/inflate.go calls any of them: `moreBits()` calls `ReadByte()`

[/src/compress/flate/inflate.go 690](https://golang.org/src/compress/flate/inflate.go)

```golang
func noEOF(e error) error {
    if e == io.EOF {
        return io.ErrUnexpectedEOF
    }

    ...
}
```

When `moreBits()` receives an error it calls `noEOF()`, which checks if it had received an `io.EOF`. If this was the case then `io.ErrUnexpectedEOF` is returned backed. Everything seems to be working as intended, and it appears that it is the user's responsibility to be on the look out for this particular case. A suggested edit to the code above to handle what appears to be defined behavior is:

```golang
func (r *compressor) decompress() []byte {
    dc := flate.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(r.content))
    defer dc.Close()
    rb, err := ioutil.ReadAll(dc)
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF && err != io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
            log.Fatalf("Err %v\n read %v", err, rb)
        }
    }
    return rb
}
```

This was checked under `go1.12.9`

Comment: I ran in this problem in a test and your solution worked there. I don't think it's right, though, but for a test, I can have a few hacks like this.

Answer (score 4):

You got the in and outputs mixed up.

`flate.NewReader` takes the compressed input as an `io.Reader` and it returns a `io.ReadCloser` that can be used to get the uncompressed output:

```
func (r *compressor) decompress() []byte {
    dc := flate.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(r.content))
    defer dc.Close()
    rb, err := ioutil.ReadAll(dc)
    if err != nil {
        if err != io.EOF {
            log.Fatalf("Err %v\n read %v", err, rb)
        }
    }
    return rb
}
```

Comment: Reading into an empty byte slice is futile. You probably meant ioutil.ReadAll or so.

Comment: another thing, i found out, is that something goes wrong in the encoding while compressing. So while decompressing one of the bytes get decoded to an EOF.

Comment: note that `compress/flate` does not uncompress gzip files. there is `compress/gzip` for that.